# toggle text next to a button

Tags: jquery, button, text

I have a table where each cell has a button in it, with this code:

```
<span class = "button"><input id="button" type="button">
```

I want to display some text to the right of it which will toggle when the button is clicked. So it would go from

[] Text

[] OtherText

without reloading the page, and it wouldn't toggle the text in other cells. How would I do this with jQuery (or something else, if there's a better way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<span class="button">
    <input id="button" type="button" value="save">
    <span id="show-text">Text</span>
</span>​
```

JS

```
$("#button").toggle(function() {
    $("#show-text").text("Other Text").stop();
}, function() {
    $("#show-text").text("Text").stop();
});​
```

Comment: This is working, but only in the first table cell. Clicking the buttons in the other cells doesn't do anything. The table is generated from a MySQL query, so it's repeating the same code for each cell. Is there a way to distinguish the buttons or do something so they'll all work?

Comment: Could put the simple markup of the table generated on http://jsfiddle.net/? That would help in better understanding of your requirement...

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="button">
    <span class="text">Text</span>
    <input id="button" type="button" />
</span>
```

JS:

```
$('.button input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prev('.text').toggle();
});
```

Comment: There is no `<button>` tag to select.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after this:

> **http://jsbin.com/azepex/1/edit**

i followed this structure of the html:

```
<span class = "button">
    <input id="button" type="button" value='toggle text' >
    <span>text.</span>
</span>
```

and this is the js:

```
$(function(){
  $('.button input[type="button"]').toggle(function(){
    $(this).next('span').text('Other text.');
  }, function(){
    $(this).next('span').text('text.');
  }); 
});
```

just checkout the above jsbin link

Comment: That version of [**toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) is deprecated.

Comment: Nope, it still works, but it's deprecated so there is no guarantee it will continue to work.

Comment: okay thanks i got it. but this kind of solution i had for now. oops.